# Polymer Core-Ajax issue

Tags: polymer

Not sure what exactly is happening here.
I am using the polymer core-ajax custom element and in IE 10 and 11 I am getting really weird behavior on the response.
It seems like when I console.log(typeof(response)) the response, the response type returns a string instead of an object, so I can't use object notation to get the properties.

The ajax object is explicitly being set with responseType: 'json'

Note see my notes in //** below

Here is my code:

```
<core-ajax id="restaurantAjax"
               auto
               url="{{baseApiUrl + 'restaurants'}}"
               on-core-response="{{restaurantsLoaded}}"
               handleAs="json">
    </core-ajax>

this.async(function() {
            this.$.restaurantService.findById(e.detail.id, (function(restaurant) {

                this.$.viewrestaurant.wines = restaurant.wines;
               //** IE complaining unable to get property wines of undefined or null
                this.$.viewrestaurant.restaurant = restaurant;
            }).bind(this));
        });

 findById: function(id, callback) {
            this.$.xhr.request({
                url: this.baseApiUrl + 'restaurants/' + id,
                callback: (function(response) {
                    console.log(typeof(response))
                    //* IE returning string instead of object 

                    var restaurant = null;
                    if (response && response.restaurant) {
                        restaurant = response.restaurant;
                    }
                    callback(restaurant);
                }).bind(this),
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },
                responseType: 'json'
            });
        }
    });
```

Can someone help me out, its happening randomly across the site, not on all Ajax objects,which is weird in itself.

Thanks,
David

Comment: I don't see where id="xhr" exists. Is this all of the code or is it a typo? If it isn't, why are you using the request() object and the `auto` attribute?

Comment: Sorry I forgot a bit of code:

Add this line under the first core-ajax element:

        <core-xhr id="xhr"></core-xhr>